# What does the error "Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure 'erase' " mean and how to fix it?

Tags: recursion, fortran, subroutine

I'm trying to use a subroutine I implemented in order to remove one element from an array at a certain index.

The subroutine:

```
subroutine erase(index,size,array)
    integer,intent(in)::index
    integer,intent(inout)::size 
    type(tcb),dimension(size),intent(inout)::array
    array(index:size-1) = array(index+1:size)
    size= size-1

  end subroutine erase
```

And this is the part where I use it:

```
 if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then
          s=size(tasks_ready_master)
          do ff=1,nthreads-2
             if (num_thread==ff+1) then

                if (tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state==STATE_READY) then 
                   tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state=STATE_RUNNING
                   free_workers_list(ff)=1
                   call  tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%f_ptr(self,var)
                   tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
                   free_workers_list(ff)=0
!!$                s=size(tasks_ready_master)
                   call erase(1,s,tasks_ready_master)
                end if
                

             end if
          end do
end if
```

I get the following error when trying to execute using 4 threads:

```
    At line 52 of file tasks.f90
Fortran runtime error: Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure 'erase'

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f5f25b2a700 in ???
#1  0x7f5f25b2b259 in ???
#2  0x7f5f25b2b8d6 in ???
#3  0x55b2ce2aef6e in __tasks_MOD_erase
    at /home/hakim/stage_hecese_HPC/OpenMP/hecese_OMP/tasks.f90:52
#4  0x55b2ce2b005a in __app_management_MOD_management._omp_fn.0
    at /home/hakim/stage_hecese_HPC/OpenMP/hecese_OMP/app_management_test.f90:237
#5  0x7f5f25990a85 in ???
#6  0x7f5f256fc608 in start_thread
    at /build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_create.c:477
#7  0x7f5f258a5292 in ???
#8  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

All I want is that ,at each time I call the subroutine `erase`, the first element of `tasks_ready_master` (array with 20 elements) gets removed (So at each call I want the size 20 to decrease by 1).

For more details, here is the subroutine management containing the call :

```
subroutine management(tasklist_GRAD,var)
    INTEGER ::ff,l
    type(tcb)::self
    type(variables)::var
    integer::s
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer:: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    integer::STATUS=0
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::free_workers_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    INTEGER(KIND=omp_lock_kind), SAVE :: lock

    CALL omp_init_lock (lock)

    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads,ff) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master,free_workers_list)
    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread 
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads

    if (nthreads<3) then
       print *, 'This program is going to exit.'
       call EXIT(STATUS)
    end if

!!$    !Thread Master (number 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then

       allocate(free_workers_list(nthreads-2)) ! liste des threads workers 

       do ff=1,nthreads-2
          free_workers_list(ff)=0 ! 2,3,..,nombre de threads-2
          print*,'the state of thread number',ff+1,' is : ',free_workers_list(ff)

       end do
    end if
    !$OMP BARRIER 

    
                  
       !Thread Application Master (number 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=1,3 ! 3 tâches
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true. ) then ! Si tâche attribuée 
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff) ! égalité de pointeurs 
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if

       !Threads Workers (number diff than 0 and 1) 
       if (nthreads==5) then  ! 5 threads ==> 3 workers 
          if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then

             do ff=1,nthreads-2
                if (num_thread==ff+1) then

                   tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
                   free_workers_list(ff)=1
                   call  tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,var)
                   tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
                   free_workers_list(ff)=0
                   s=size(tasks_ready_master)
                   call erase(1,s,tasks_ready_master)
                end if
             end do

          end if
end subroutine management
```

Comment: It is pretty much self-descriptive, isn't it? You are calling a procedure recursively without declaring it `recursive`. Did you look for other questions with the same error message?

Comment: A different question is why such a recursive call happens. Are there any defined assignments or operators in place? Show the complete [mcve].

Comment: @VladimirF yes I looked for other questions with the same error message but I didn't find something useful.

Comment: You must show a [mcve]. Are there any defined assignments? Are there any `bind(C)` anywhere? What is your compiler version? What debugging did you do? Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: There are bugs in compilers, such as this one https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80361 in gfortran. And I remember a different one that involved `bind(c)`.

Comment: @VladimirF My compiler version is gfortran 9.3.0. I didn't use `bind(C)`. I use the flags `-g -fcheck=all` for debugging. I edited the code in order to show you the whole error I got.

Comment: Please really isolate a small program that everyone can compile and run. It might be a compiler bug but it is impossible to report one without a real [mcve]. No, just the subroutine is not enough. Try disabling OpenMP. Try `-frecursive`. Try changing other options.